# How to apply custom validator on Form group control

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have Root FormGroup that contains different different FormGroup .I want to apply validator on control between two or more FormGroup .

**For Example:**

I have to two FormGroup `mobile` and `workPhone` and each FormGroup has different controls such as `number` etc.

Now i have to write validator  on both mobile and workPhone to become one optional on enter value in number control.
for more refrence please see the example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-ywydcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

how to achieve this Initial both control will be required. But when I enter the work phone number, the mobile number should become optional
And Vice Versa.

**appcomponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ValidationErrors,
  ValidatorFn,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  rootForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.rootForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        mobile: new FormGroup({
          countryCode: new FormControl('+1'),
          number: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        }),

        workPhone: new FormGroup({
          countryCode: new FormControl('+1'),
          number: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        }),
      },
      { Validators: EitherMobileOrWorkPhoneRequired }
    );
  }

  public onSubmit(value) {
    console.log('Form Invalid:' + this.rootForm.invalid);
  }
}

export const EitherMobileOrWorkPhoneRequired: ValidatorFn = (
  control: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null => {
  console.log(control);
  return null;
};
```

If any other details required. Please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write a full answer, but here's a fixed stackblitz fork. https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-bqs6c9 Basically you check if either child group have value filled. If not, you add error to your parent form.

Comment: User the rxweb angular reactive form validation to achieve complex validation scenarios
https://docs.rxweb.io/getting-started

Comment: @TotallyNewb its not working as expected...as you see in stackblitz fork provided...```number: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),``` and ```*ngIf="this.rootForm.get('mobile').get('number').status == 'INVALID'```  lines modified....In other word still form controls status is ```INVALID```.

Comment: My fork IS working as expected, at least regarding your requirements. Either one of two fields needs to be filled. The second becomes optional. The form is invalid if neither is filled, valid if one or both are filled. If you have some additional requirements, you forgot to mention them.

Comment: @TotallyNewb please review your fork.its doesn't contains ```Validator.required``` in formcontrol in ```ngOninit```.you have removed validator and just updating control error..but control status not updating  if one field has value. And form status should be VALID on submit with one field.